# Mixing temp table and real tables in query

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

Why does one of these queries work and the other does not? I wrote the working query, then made the table temporary and it has to be rewritten to have the temp table on the outside.

This is the data in the tables:

**tmpTASItemQtyInventDim:**

```
|ItemId | InventDimId  | InventQty |
|-------|--------------|-----------|
|73016  | Dim 11542913 | 0         |
```

**SalesLine:**

```
|Sales Id    |Line No | ItemId | InventDimId  | SalesQty  |
|------------|--------|--------|--------------|-----------|
|SO120036796 |       1| 73016  | Dim 11542913 | 2         |
```

**Does Not work:**

```
select firstonly tmpTASItemQtyInventDim
    join itemId, InventDimId, sum(salesQty) from salesLine
    group by itemId, InventDimId
    where salesLine.SalesId == 'SO120036796'  &&
          tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.ItemId == salesLine.ItemId     &&
          tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.InventDimId    == salesLine.InventDimId    &&
          tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.InventQty      < salesLine.SalesQty;

if (tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.ItemId)
    info("Insufficient Qty");
else
    info("Good qty");
```

**Works:**

```
select firstonly itemId, InventDimId, sum(salesQty) from salesLine
    group by itemId, InventDimId
    where salesLine.SalesId     == 'SO120036796'
    exists join tmpTASItemQtyInventDim
        where tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.ItemId == salesLine.ItemId     &&
              tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.InventDimId    == salesLine.InventDimId    &&
              tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.InventQty      < salesLine.SalesQty;

if (salesLine.ItemId)
    info("Insufficient Qty");
else
    info("Good Qty");
```

Both should output `Insufficient Qty`, but the first says `Good Qty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory I think you need to group by on the first table as well
see
http://axatluegisdorf.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/select-group-by-and-join-order-by.html

```
select firstonly ITEMID,InventDimId 
  FROM  tmpTASItemQtyInventDim
  GROUP BY ITEMID,InventDimId
join itemId, InventDimId, sum(salesQty) 
from salesLine
 group by itemId, InventDimId
where salesLine.SalesId == 'SO120036796'  &&
      tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.ItemId == salesLine.ItemId     &&
      tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.InventDimId    == salesLine.InventDimId    &&
      tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.InventQty      < salesLine.SalesQty;

if (tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.ItemId)
   info("Insufficient Qty");
else
   info("Good qty");
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Doesn't make complete sense to why I need to do that, but it works.

Comment: I think its because the query without the group by is equivalent to `code`Select SalesLine.ItemId,SalesLine.InventDimId from tmpTASItemQtyInventDim Inner join salesLine ON tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.ItemId == salesLine.ItemId     AND
      tmpTASItemQtyInventDim.InventDimId    == salesLine.InventDimId....`code` If "your does not work was" to test SalesLine.ItemId It  think is would produce the correct result also

Answer (score 1):

Mixing temp tables and real tables is like biking a cobbled road. You do not always get what you want think you get, and the [performance sometimes sucks](http://mybhat.blogspot.dk/2012/05/joining-permanent-table-with-temp-table.html).

In AX 2012 you could use TempDB which work more predictable.

See also [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Temporary_tables).

Comment: Very interesting post.  I should use trace parcer sometimes and really check the cost of my queries I think.